# Matching TD heights in HTML emails

Tags: html, email, html-table, email-client

I'm currently building a HTML email and I'm having real issues with making two TD's the same height on all email clients.

It's a responsive email so I've separated the columns into two tables instead of nesting it all under the same one so they can snap underneath each other on mobiles.

I've tried stating the heights in both the TD's and the tables both with little success, in the end I even threw in a min-height.

I should say that it works fine on all web based browsers (except yahoo) my big problem is with outlook 2007 & 2010 which is what the client actually tests the emails on annoyingly enough.

Here's a sample:

```
<!-- square panels wrapper -->
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="square_panel_wrapper"><tr><td>

    <!-- square panels container -->
    <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="square_panel_container"><tr><td>

        <!-- left table -->
        <table width="290" height="640" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="square_panel_left" style="border: 1px solid #c8c9cb; height: 640px; min-height: 640px;">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #414042; line-height:1.5em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae commodo leo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #414042; line-height:1.5em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae commodo leo</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- right table -->
        <table align="right" width="290" height="640" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="square_panel_right" style="border: 1px solid #c8c9cb; height: 640px; min-height: 640px;">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #414042; line-height:1.5em; margin-top: 0px;  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae commodo leo. Aenean molestie tristique erat a consequat. Vestibulum nec nunc vel velit ornare fermentum in eget ipsum. Mauris venenatis volutpat malesuada. Curabitur fringilla libero at turpis tempor egestas quis rhoncus quam.  
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #414042; line-height:1.5em; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae commodo leo</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

    </td></tr></table>

</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If height for `<td>` always fixed, you can try to insert `<img src="http://somesite.com/dot.png" style="width:1px;height:640px" />` in `<td>`, this transparent image will be invisible and have fixed height, so your`<td>` will have the same min-height as image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as correctly sad wearwoolf you can force use min-height attribute for td - put invisible image in td, or wrap you td into div.
Example for first case:

```
<td><img style="float:left;min-height:50px;visibility:hidden;width:0px;">12345</td>
```